# search through a bitmap and find colour of pixels out of range exception error

Tags: vb.net

I need to find the colour for each pixel in the bitmap and then store the colour of the pixel below and next to it for comparison later on. However, I get an out of range exception error in the for loop. I do not know why this occurs, what can I do to fix it?

```
Dim img As New Bitmap(bitmapbox.Image)
    MsgBox(img.Size.ToString)
    MsgBox(img.Height.ToString)
    Dim pixelcolor As Color
    Dim pixelcolorbelow As Color
    Dim pixelcolornext As Color
    Dim notstoretwice As Boolean = False

    For k As Integer = 1 To img.Height - 1
        For i As Integer = 1 To img.Width - 1

            pixelcolor = img.GetPixel(i, k)
            pixelcolorbelow = img.GetPixel(i, k + 1)
            pixelcolornext = img.GetPixel(i + 1, k)
            If pixelcolor.R >= pixelcolornext.R - 20 Or pixelcolor.R <= pixelcolornext.R + 20 And pixelcolor.R >= pixelcolorbelow.R - 20 And pixelcolor.R <= pixelcolorbelow.R + 20 Then
                notstoretwice = True
                yordinate.Add(k)
                xordinate.Add(i)
                If pixelcolor.G >= pixelcolornext.G - 20 And pixelcolor.G <= pixelcolornext.G + 20 And pixelcolor.R >= pixelcolorbelow.G - 20 And pixelcolor.G <= pixelcolorbelow.G + 20 And notstoretwice = False Then
                    notstoretwice = True
                    yordinate.Add(k)
                    xordinate.Add(i)
                    If pixelcolor.B >= pixelcolornext.B - 20 And pixelcolor.B <= pixelcolornext.B + 20 And pixelcolor.R >= pixelcolorbelow.B - 20 And pixelcolor.B <= pixelcolorbelow.B + 20 And notstoretwice = False Then
                        notstoretwice = True
                        yordinate.Add(k)
                        xordinate.Add(i)
                        ' similar color to the selected color
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            notstoretwice = False

        Next

    Next
    pb.Height = 210
    pb.Width = 110
    Me.Controls.Add(pb)

    Dim flag As Bitmap = New Bitmap(200, 100)
    Dim flagGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(flag)
    Dim red As Integer = 0
    Dim white As Integer = 11
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim f As Integer
    For m As Integer = 0 To yordinate.Count - 1
        j = yordinate(m)
        f = xordinate(m)
        flagGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, j, f, 100, 100)
    Next
    pb.Image = flag
end sub
```

Comment: When you debug, which exact line produces the exception?  What exact message does the exception give you?  What are the exact runtime values of the variables on that line?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the exception because of these lines:

```vb
pixelcolorbelow = img.GetPixel(i, k + 1)
pixelcolornext = img.GetPixel(i + 1, k)
```

Doing it like this, you get an IndexOutOfRange when it goes to get the below/next pixel when you reach the end of the respective collection. You will need to add a conditional check to make sure that you are not at the end or loop to the second to last height/width. I'd personally go with the latter:

```vb
For k As Integer = 1 To img.Height - 2
    For i As Integer = 1 To img.Width - 2
        ' ...
    Next
Next
```

Comment: You’re actually a genius thanks for this mate.